# A confusing sign

Tags: english

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #12: mobile-friendly puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7484/monthly-topic-challenge-12-mobile-friendly-puzzles).</sub>

I saw this posted on a sign, but couldn’t make sense of it. What was it trying to say?

> By ridge loses own aster or routing trough md un.
> Paring imitations, ties oline (als to FA).
> Dive lowly raveling pon cures hen etra rain/freeing.

Comment: One for your [MTC](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7484/monthly-topic-challenge-12-mobile-friendly-puzzles)?

Comment: @Stiv probably not - however I am really loving all the MTC submissions as I've been on the road quite a bit this summer. Haven't managed to solve any yet...

Comment: I would have thought this one was perfect - possibly the prime example (and much more apt than some of mine, I'd say...). Do consider it! Ultimately your choice though :)

Comment: @Stiv well I don't feel this is my best work in terms of the challenge and was planning to sit it out anyway and see what others came up with, but since you are so persuasive...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Bay bridge closes down Easter for grouting through mid Jun. 
> Parking limitations, times online (also top FAQ). 
> Drive slowly traveling upon curves when extra rainy/freezing.

> Sorry, but I really wanted one of each letter. So I stole them off of the sign (and moved the remaining letters to fix the spacing). Luckily for me, it happened to have them all — and in order, one per word.